# ASP.NET MVC 5 Setting textbox value from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've recently transfered from ASP.NET Web Forms to MVC, I've managed to get my desired textbox values and run some calculations on them, because there isn't much help available for MVC 5 I can't find any information on how to return the value to a textbox in the same view from the controller.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: There are many examples for this and the methods for the older versions still apply. Here's (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view) even an updated version for a start guide that's not much different from previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

Store the Initial Value in a ViewBag inside the controller

```
    ViewBag.InitialValue = "initialvalue";
```

Then you can access the initial Value inside your View like so

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.somename, null, new { @value = ViewBag.InitialValue })
```

that should do.